# How to have both highlighting and literal html tags within a markdown code block?

Tags: markdown

Is there a way to be able to mark/highlight a segment of text and also have literal `<html>` tags within that same block? I am trying to achieve something like [Listing 3.3](http://conqueringthecommandline.com/book/curl#code-curl-redirect-info) here. It doesn't work with fenced code blocks because using `<mark>` to highlight the text has no effect, and it also doesn't work with `<pre><code>` because the `<html>` tags within the `<pre><code>` tags will not be interpreted literally. I am using MacDown with GFM.

Comment: Which Markdown implementation are you using? In what context? The [original project](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) doesn't support highlighting at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it appears that Macdown [uses](https://github.com/uranusjr/macdown/blob/master/Podfile#L9) hoedown as its Markdown parser. Doesn't seem to be much [documentation](https://github.com/hoedown/hoedown/wiki/Getting-started) about it. So I'll give the generic answer that will work in most any implementation.

If you want a mix of HTML and raw HTML in the same code block, you will either need to build your own extension which does what you want or manually build the code block yourself. Building your own extension is beyond this answer, so lets focus on the later.

First, you will need to wrap your code block in `<pre><code>` tags and be sure not to indent the first line of your block so that the parser sees it as raw HTML.

Second, to include HTML to "highlight" (or whatever you want to do), manually create your HTML tags to wrap the various pieces of your code block.

Finally, to have literal HTML displayed in the code block, you will need to escape the HTML manually (or perhaps use a tool to escape it for you).

Combine the three together, and insert into your Markdown document. For example, to replicate the example you point to do this:

```
<pre><code><span class="hll">HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily</span>
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://quiet-waters-1228.herokuapp.com/hello
Server: thin 1.6.1 codename Death Proof
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: e9785070-173c-4e8a-bbf5-1686806cbd6b
X-Runtime: 0.007276
X-Ua-Compatible: chrome=1
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

&lt;html&gt;
  &lt;body&gt;
    You are being
    &lt;a href="http://quiet-waters-1228.herokuapp.com/hello"&gt;redirected&lt;/a&gt;.
  &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Note that the first line is wrapped in a `<span>` with a class assigned to it as a styling hook. It just needs some CSS. Also note that the literal HTML later in the block is manually escaped with `&gt;` and `&lt;` to replace the angle brackets. The above will render as:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://quiet-waters-1228.herokuapp.com/hello
Server: thin 1.6.1 codename Death Proof
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id: e9785070-173c-4e8a-bbf5-1686806cbd6b
X-Runtime: 0.007276
X-Ua-Compatible: chrome=1
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
  <body>
    You are being
    <a href="http://quiet-waters-1228.herokuapp.com/hello">redirected</a>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course you need to include proper CSS for the `class="hll"` to work, which we don't get here on SO. Should work on your own site where you can provide your own CSS though.